# Unexpected behavior of the Python logging module with info and warning messages

Tags: python, logging

I have a question regarding logging module in Python.
If I instantiate a logger and set its level to INFO without adding any handlers, then I expect that info messages will be printed on the screen.
However, in reality, warning messages are printed but info messages are not.
After adding explicitly a handler, both levels are printed.

Precisely, the following small script:

```py
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info("This is an info message")
logger.warning("This is a warning message")

print("*** Add a stream handler explicitly")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("This is an info message")
logger.warning("This is a warning message")
```

gives output

```
This is a warning message
*** Add a stream handler explicitly
This is an info message
This is a warning message
```

(checked in Python 3.7.6 and 3.8.2).

I would expect that either no messages are printed without a handler, or both levels are printed after setting level to INFO.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru). It's a really simple to use tool and for me it's very intuitive.

You can add a default logger just using this line:

```
from loguru import logger
```

If you want to change the logging level, just setup the logger like this:

```
logger.remove()  # This disables the default logger
logger.add(sys.stderr, level="INFO")  # This adds a default logger (format and colors included) but at the logging level you need
```

And that's it. All the scripts that use the loguru logger in your code will be set up like this. By default it outputs to stderr but you can change it however you need.